# How to add an empty column to a list of dataframes in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Say I have the list of dataframes:

```
#Example data frame columns
Image <- c("001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001")
Size <- c("Big", "Small", "Medium", "Tiny", "Big", "Small", "Medium", "Tiny", "Big", "Small", "Medium", "Tiny")
n <- c(111778, 56, 7099, 3, 3682081, 88, 9078, 7, 198346, 422, 30077, 8)

#make example data frame
data <- data.frame(Image, Size, n)

#Split dataframe into a list of dataframes
df <- split(data, f = data$Image) 
df
```

How could I add an empty column (named new), to each of the dataframes contained in this list.

I have tried

```
df$new <- NA
```

But nothing happens with no error

There are much more complicated answers to this question, based on specific conditions etc but I get lost trying to simplify it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Your `n` has an extra comma `,`, remove it.
2. Your `df` is a `list`, not a frame, so you cannot just reference a column in it with the `$` special operator. You can either add the `new` column before `split`ting it, or add it specially to each split-frame.

First option:

```r
data$new <- NA
df <- split(data, f = data$Image) 
df
# $`001`
#    Image   Size       n new
# 1    001    Big  111778  NA
# 2    001  Small      56  NA
# 3    001 Medium    7099  NA
# 4    001   Tiny       3  NA
# 5    001    Big 3682081  NA
# 6    001  Small      88  NA
# 7    001 Medium    9078  NA
# 8    001   Tiny       7  NA
# 9    001    Big  198346  NA
# 10   001  Small     422  NA
# 11   001 Medium   30077  NA
# 12   001   Tiny       8  NA
```

Second option, add to each frame in the list:

```r
### original data, without `new`
df <- split(data, f = data$Image) 
df <- lapply(df, `[<-`, "new", value = NA)
df
# $`001`
#    Image   Size       n new
# 1    001    Big  111778  NA
# 2    001  Small      56  NA
# 3    001 Medium    7099  NA
# 4    001   Tiny       3  NA
# 5    001    Big 3682081  NA
# 6    001  Small      88  NA
# 7    001 Medium    9078  NA
# 8    001   Tiny       7  NA
# 9    001    Big  198346  NA
# 10   001  Small     422  NA
# 11   001 Medium   30077  NA
# 12   001   Tiny       8  NA
```

---

Data

```r
data <- structure(list(Image = c("001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001"), Size = c("Big", "Small", "Medium", "Tiny", "Big", "Small", "Medium", "Tiny", "Big", "Small", "Medium", "Tiny"), n = c(111778, 56, 7099, 3, 3682081, 88, 9078, 7, 198346, 422, 30077, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Recently I read the "friendly" warning in `?transform` and now I am skeptical about using it. Alternatively we could do `lapply(df, \`[<-\`, 'new', value=NA)`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Data

```
Image <- c("001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "002", "002", "002", "002")
Size <- c("Big", "Small", "Medium", "Tiny", "Big", "Small", "Medium", "Tiny", "Big", "Small", "Medium", "Tiny")
n <- c(111778, 56, 7099, 3, 3682081, 88, 9078, 7, 198346, 422, 30077, 8)

data <- data.frame(Image, Size, n)
df <- split(data, f = data$Image)
```

#### Code

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(df,function(x) x %>% mutate(New = NA))
```

#### Output

```
$`001`
  Image   Size       n New
1   001    Big  111778  NA
2   001  Small      56  NA
3   001 Medium    7099  NA
4   001   Tiny       3  NA
5   001    Big 3682081  NA
6   001  Small      88  NA
7   001 Medium    9078  NA
8   001   Tiny       7  NA

$`002`
   Image   Size      n New
9    002    Big 198346  NA
10   002  Small    422  NA
11   002 Medium  30077  NA
12   002   Tiny      8  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Data taken from @Vinícius Félix (many thanks):

**Base R:**

```
lapply(df, function(x) { x["New_Col"] <- NA; x })
```

**tidyverse:**

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  map(., ~(.x %>% mutate(New_Col = NA)))
```

```
$`001`
  Image   Size       n New_Col
1   001    Big  111778      NA
2   001  Small      56      NA
3   001 Medium    7099      NA
4   001   Tiny       3      NA
5   001    Big 3682081      NA
6   001  Small      88      NA
7   001 Medium    9078      NA
8   001   Tiny       7      NA

$`002`
   Image   Size      n New_Col
9    002    Big 198346      NA
10   002  Small    422      NA
11   002 Medium  30077      NA
12   002   Tiny      8      NA
```